# Confirm box script issues in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Script to exectue in one tab (chrome browser)

```
var popupFlag = confirm(popupMsg);
    if (popupFlag) {

      //console.log(timeDiffFlagSuccess);
       } else {
      stopWorker();
      doLogout();
    }
```

When we open new tab in chrome else statement executes surprisingly.

In other browser, script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is wrong.

It should be `elseif` instead of `else`.

```
elseif  (!popupFlag)
```

However, it can be done much simpler than that by just using a `if` / `else`

```
if (popupFlag) {
    //console.log(timeDiffFlagSuccess);
} else {
    stopWorker();
    doLogout();
}
```

Comment: This is done already , which is actually not working.Posted on google chrome forum as well.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/BFoUyWlTx6I/v9kn0tERDgAJ